# html email Background gradient not visible in outlook app

Tags: html, outlook

The background gradient property not works in outlook app. The desktop outlook shows the gradient. 
can one knows the solution to display gradient color in outlook app.  :)

I used the the following code for desktop outlook :

```
        <center>
        <![endif]-->
```

what is used for outlook App ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Outlook doesn't support all CSS, If you want to add gradient in background so design a image and call it as `background-image`. Hope this will help you

Comment: no Zaln khan, i need css in place of image, do you have any idea to how to display in place of background image. I am implementing it on email template.

Comment: `background-color` property is not fully supported by Outlook desktop app that's why we use background image instead.

Comment: actually i need gradient in background not solid color. Do you have any jugad or trick for this ?

Comment: Yes that was only the trick to do that. Because I've worked on more than hundreds of email templates.